# GlassFish 3.1 LDAP-Realm via ActiveDirectory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, active-directory, glassfish

There have been some questions about this topic here but none of the answers helped or the threads seemed to have died... so here goes another one:

I am trying to have authentification for my webapps handled via an ActiveDirectory Server. Configuration of the realm in domain.xml is as follows:

```
<auth-realm name="ActiveDirectory" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm">
  <property description="null" name="directory" value="ldap://ad.local:389"></property>
  <property description="null" name="base-dn" value="DC=ad,DC=local"></property>
  <property name="jaas-context" value="ldapRealm"></property>
  <property name="assign-groups" value="Users"></property>
  <property name="search-filter" value="(&amp;(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))"></property>
  <property name="search-bind-password" value="topsecret"></property>
  <property name="group-search-filter" value="(&amp;(objectCategory=group)(member=%d))"></property>
  <property name="search-bind-dn" value="CN=read only,OU=@ServiceAccounts,DC=ad,DC=local"></property>
</auth-realm>
```

Also, this JVM-Option is set (as stated in many tutorials):

```
<jvm-options>-Djava.naming.referral=follow</jvm-options>
```

web.xml for the application is setup this (yes, very basic):

```
...
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>OnlyAD</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>/SubgroupFacade</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/SubgroupFacade</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ActiveDirectory</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>Users</role-name>
</security-role>
...
```

Starting Glassfish works fine. Visiting the SubgroupFacade-Servlet works, too: the login-box comes up. I enter a valid username and the appropriate password and... the window simply appears again.

The log shows, that the raw connection and plain-user lookup works, but group-lookup fails with one (probably two) Exceptions:

```
WARNUNG: SEC1106: Error during LDAP search with filter [(&(objectCategory=group)(member=CN=Someuser Joe,OU=Users,OU=Fizzlecorp,DC=ad,DC=local))].
WARNUNG: SEC1000: Caught exception.
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'DC=ad,DC=local'
...
WARNUNG: SEC1106: Error during LDAP search with filter [(&(objectclass=groupofuniquenames)(objectclass=*groupofurls*))].
WARNUNG: SEC1000: Caught exception.
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'DC=ad,DC=local'
...
```

Running the LDAP-Queries in an external application (for example a simple ldapsearch on a terminal) works. I do get all groups of Joe Someuser. However, the second query (`(&(objectclass=groupofuniquenames)(objectclass=*groupofurls*))`) does not return any results... and I wasn't able to get any information about what this query is supposed to do.

I hope somebody out there has an idea about what's going wrong here. This one keeps beating me since I came to work this morning (it's now late afternoon here...).

Thanks in advance!
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Add to `<auth-realm>`
property
`<property name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"></property>`

It helped me.